# How to use find where query in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been writing a lot of MySQL lately so I've forgotten how to write some Mongoose queries. I am trying to search my database to find stocks where the user is the same as the req.params.user. below is the route and my Schema so you can see what's going on. I'm running it in Post man, but it's giving me a "Cannot GET /stock/user-stocks/Sina" Error. I also left a sample stock in my DB for reference

```
router.get('user-stocks/:user', (req, res) => {
    Stock.find({ user: toString(req.params.user)})
    .then((stocks) => res.json(stocks))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

const stockSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: String, required: true},
    symbol: {type: String, required: true},
    target: {type: Number, required: false},
    stop: {type: Number, required: false},
    description: {type: String, required: false},
    date: {type: Date, required: false}
})

{
        "_id": "5ff284d07b93cd434cae9a08",
        "user": "Sina",
        "symbol": "AAPL",
        "target": 200,
        "stop": 100,
        "description": "Get money",
        "date": "2021-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Comment: Did you mount the route in your server `app.use('/stock', require([your route path]))`? Also, the route needs to start with `/` as `router.get('/user-stocks/:user',....)`

Comment: Thanks lol, i missed the / in the get lol. It works now